# Throwing a RuntimeException, unreachable line

Tags: java, exception

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    public static void throwit(){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        try{
            System.out.println("Hello");
            throwit(); // doesn't compile if this line is replaced with throw new RuntimeException.
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }   
    }
}
```

I was experimenting with try-catch-finally and throwing exceptions and I couldn't figure out why I was getting an error one way while the other way it compiled fine, even though they do the same thing.

I have a method called `throwit()` which throw's a new `RuntimeException`. I called it under the try block in the main method and everything compiled fine and worked. However if I replaced the `throwit();` with just `throw new RuntimeException` than the line below that is unreachable.

But, isn't `throwit()` and `throw new RuntimeException` doing the same thing? `throwit()` throws a new `RunetimeException` and just saying `throw new RuntimeException` does the same thing as well.

So, my question is why does the method which throws a new `RuntimeException` compile with no errors while just directly calling `throw new RuntimeException` causes an unreachable line, even though they do the exact same thing? If anyone could answer this for me that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [static code analyser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) in the Java compiler cannot determine that the line is unreachable when the method is hard-coded to throw the `RuntimeException`; whereas, when you hardcode the throws line the compiler can detect that the next statement is unreachable and will not allow you to compile.

[JLS-14.21 Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) says in part,

> The idea is that there must be some possible execution path from the beginning of the constructor, method, instance initializer, or static initializer that contains the statement to the statement itself. The analysis takes into account the structure of statements. Except for the special treatment of while, do, and for statements whose condition expression has the constant value true, the values of expressions are not taken into account in the flow analysis.

Comment: Since methods can be located in other compilation units looking inside of other methods to see if they actually return or not is not feasible anyway. I think some languages have a special modifier keyword for functions that never return to support this.

Comment: Thank you Elliott, that makes so much more sense now.